# Neural network to control movement and "home in" on a target

Tags: neural-networks, getting-started

I'm a software developer who keeps trying (and failing) to get my head around AI and neural networks. There is one area that sparked my interest recently - simulating a mouse "homing in" on a piece of cheese by following the smell. Based on the rule that moving closer to the cheese = stronger smell = good, then it feels like it should be quite a simple problem to solve - in theory at least!

My thought process was to start by placing the mouse and cheese in random positions on the screen. I would then move the mouse one step in a random direction and measure its distance to the cheese, and if it's closer than before (stronger smell) then that's good. This is where I come unstuck on the theory - this "feedback" somehow needs to modify the mechanism used to move the mouse, gradually refining it until the mouse is able to head straight towards the cheese.
Once "trained", I should be able to reposition the cheese and expect the mouse to travel to it more quickly. *Note I'm also keeping things simple by not having obstacles for the mouse to negotiate around.*

How on earth would this be implemented with a NN? I understand the basic concepts, but I find that things unravel once I start looking at real code! The examples I've seen typically start by training the NN from a data set, but this doesn't seem to apply here as it feels like the only training available is "on the fly" as the mouse moves around (i.e. closer = good, further away = bad). I'm assuming the brain has some kind of "reward mechanism" triggered by a stronger smell of cheese.

Am I barking up the wrong tree - either with my thought process, or NN not being a good fit for this problem? This isn't homework btw, just something that I've been puzzling over in the back of my mind.

Comment: You have stumbled on reinforcement learning. I’ll give a better answer later but searching for ‘gridworld reinforcement learning’ will head you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a NEAT algorithm for this one. Basically, you "breed" the right network that does the best every generation. Then Rinse and repeat. Doesn't require a training datbase. Bots compete and evolve as they go.

For example, this demonstration shows how Neataptic.js teaches a bunch of bots to follow a target:
https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/targetseeking/

Here is more complex problem - a game of Agar.io:
https://wagenaartje.github.io/neataptic/articles/agario/